# Opera giving a div a top margin on page load

Tags: jquery, css

OK, so I have been having a weird problem in Opera with my website.
It's pretty obvious.

My site:
http://fortiswebsystems.com/.

**Problem:** In Opera, the center div has a large margin from the top when the page is refreshed. As soon as I hover over the navbar, it rights itself with a jerk up.

It works normal in FF and Chrome. Please help! Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Fixed. See my fix below

Comment: oh boy. please tell me why this got voted down. its a simple question

Comment: FWIW, you might want to change the doctype to HTML 5. It doesn't validate as XHTML strict and some of the errors would likely go away with a different DTD: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffortiswebsystems.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks, I will change it. Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: Could just be the DTD but I'm downloading Opera to take a look.

Comment: It's not the DTD... Just changed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here's a working JS fiddle so other people can debug it too: http://jsfiddle.net/73HGV/1/. I noticed that the "jumping" started once I added a reference to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I found it. Opera didn't like my margin in the underlying div `#content-container`. I moved the top margin to the `#container` div and it works now

Comment: I would say that's probably either due to an interpretation of margin collapse (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) or just a bug in Opera. I found that if I faded the whole document out and then back in it was positioned correctly, which indicates there is nothing structurally wrong with the document.